# How to use Bing search api in Java

Tags: java, bing

I need to extract search results from Bing. Is there any available Java code to achieve this ?

Answer (score 7):

[This MSDN forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/DataMarket/thread/f93738b4-b4eb-4f8a-83c6-6f97c66cd2fb/) has alot of answers and examples.

Also, when you buy or subscribe to a dataset on Azure, they have a java example. Here's an example

> Go to the [odata4j](http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/) site and
>   download the latest release.
>
> Add odata4j-clientbundle-x.x.jar to your Java build path.
>
> You can use the following code to call the service.

```
ODataConsumer c = ODataConsumers
    .newBuilder("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/")
    .setClientBehaviors(OClientBehaviors.basicAuth("accountKey", "{your account key here}"))
    .build();

OQueryRequest<OEntity> oRequest = c.getEntities("Web")
    .custom("Query", "stackoverflow bing api");

Enumerable<OEntity> entities = oRequest.execute();
```

Comment: Quite hard to find a working example, and that is one perfectly working one! Thanks.

Comment: Remember to encode your query and add `'` to the beginning and end of the query. `String query = URLEncoder.encode("'stackoverflow bing api'", "UTF-8");` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters for more details.