# Bing Search API error using odata4j

Tags: java, azure, bing-api, odata4j

I am trying to run Bing search API. I used odata4j and tried the code provided here:
[How to use Bing search api in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648847/how-to-use-bing-search-api-in-java/25031594#25031594)

```
ODataConsumer c = ODataConsumers
    .newBuilder("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search")
    .setClientBehaviors(OClientBehaviors.basicAuth("accountKey", "{your account key here}"))
    .build();

OQueryRequest<OEntity> oRequest = c.getEntities("Web")
    .custom("Query", "stackoverflow bing api");

Enumerable<OEntity> entities = oRequest.execute();
```

After I registered in the bing service, I obtained the key and placed it inside the double quotation in the above code. I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Expected status OK, found Bad Request. Server response:
Parameter: Query is not of type String
    at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyClient.doRequest(ODataJerseyClient.java:165)
    at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataClient.getEntities(AbstractODataClient.java:69)
    at org.odata4j.consumer.ConsumerQueryEntitiesRequest.doRequest(ConsumerQueryEntitiesRequest.java:59)
    at org.odata4j.consumer.ConsumerQueryEntitiesRequest.getEntries(ConsumerQueryEntitiesRequest.java:50)
    at org.odata4j.consumer.ConsumerQueryEntitiesRequest.execute(ConsumerQueryEntitiesRequest.java:40)
    at BingAPI.main(BingAPI.java:20)
Caused by: org.odata4j.exceptions.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Unknown content type text/plain;charset=utf-8
    at org.odata4j.format.FormatParserFactory.getParser(FormatParserFactory.java:78)
    at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyClient.doRequest(ODataJerseyClient.java:161)
    ... 5 more
```

I could not figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

All what you need is to set your query like that %27stackoverflow bing api%27

Here is my source code:

```
ODataConsumer consumer = ODataConsumers
            .newBuilder("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/")
            .setClientBehaviors(
                    OClientBehaviors.basicAuth("accountKey",
                            "{My Account ID}"))
            .build();

    System.out.println(consumer.getServiceRootUri() + consumer.toString());

    OQueryRequest<OEntity> oQueryRequest = consumer.getEntities("Web")
            .custom("Query", "%27stackoverflow%27");

    System.out.println("oRequest : " + oQueryRequest);

    Enumerable<OEntity> entities = oQueryRequest.execute();
    System.out.println(entities.elementAt(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can further try different queries with different filters by keep adding name-value pairs by using .custom("Type of parameter","parameter") of the oQueryrequest object.Say you want to search for indian food but you want only small square images.

```
    ODataConsumer consumer = ODataConsumers
            .newBuilder("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/")
            .setClientBehaviors(
                    OClientBehaviors.basicAuth("accountKey",
                            "YOUR ACCOUNT KEY"))
            .build();

    System.out.println(consumer.getServiceRootUri() + consumer.toString());

    OQueryRequest<OEntity> oQueryRequest = consumer.getEntities("Image")
            .custom("Query", "%27indian food%27");    
    oQueryRequest.custom("Adult", "%27Moderate%27");
    oQueryRequest.custom("ImageFilters", "%27Size:Small+Aspect:Square%27");
    System.out.println("oRequest : " + oQueryRequest);

    Enumerable<OEntity> entities = oQueryRequest.execute();

    int count = 0;
    Iterator<OEntity> iter = entities.iterator();
    System.out.println(iter.next());
```